# Do I need a "to" for a second infinitive in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives

> It was common practice to first test and execute a program's source code by hand before using a computer.
>
> It was common practice to first test and **to** execute a program's source code by hand before using a computer.

The first version of the sentence is without a second **to**, the second version includes a second **to**. Which one is correct?

Comment: First: I don't see this as proofreading--the OP is asking whether the second "to" belongs. This is a specific question, as opposed to the general proofreading question "is this sentence okay?". Second: the answer (in case this question gets closed). The position of the adverb "first" is incompatible with a second "to", since you want it to modify both verbs. You would need to put the "first" after "hand" if you want to put in a second "to". (There's also no reason to do this. It reads better with just one "to". If you had a long verb clause after the first "to", it might not.)

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you very much for your answer. I also prefer the first version of the sentence (with one`to`) ..  I am asking because my MS Word is underlining the word `execute` green suggesting to use `executes` instead which doesn't make any sense to me. (my mother tongue is German)

Comment: @Marc: the MS Word grammar checker does not understand the grammar of complicated sentences. Ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, you are free to either omit or repeat *to* in an elliptical, parallel construction like this. However, in this case the word *first* stands between *to* and the infinitive, and so you cannot repeat *to* while omitting *first* in the second branch. Repeating both *to* and *first*, however, sounds a little awkward, perhaps because it is a bit redundant. It is possible, but I recommend leaving out *to* and *first* in the second branch.

Comment: +1 *First* is redundant with *before*; unless (I'm looking at you, @marcwellman) OP means "first to test and then to execute ... before &c.

Comment: @StoneyB: Gracias! But I don't think *first...then* would change the meaning of the sentence, given that both would naturally be carried out in the order in which they are written?

Comment: Ya got me. I don't know what "executing source code by hand" means, or how you "test" it without "executing" it. It's been a quarter-century since I was a programmer.

Comment: @StoneyB - It sounds like they're going in the way-way-way-back machine, where you would walk through the program line by line, keeping track of register values on paper to see what the results would be before you actually put it through the computer.

Comment: I'll go with this. Of course, you could say *"It was common practice first to test and to execute a program's source code by hand"*, but even with a background in programming I can't imagine what possible different activities *test* and *execute* might mean in such a context.

Comment: @Lynn: You can "dry run" high-level code just as much as machine code. And "source code" has no real implications as to the *level* of the code. One word in some modern languages might execute more machine code instructions than you could write in a week (back in the day, sigh! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  I know you *can* do it, but the sentence in the example says that it was "common practice" to do it.   The only time I am aware that it was "common" to do so was back in the very early days of programming.  But I expect we're veering away from the main issue in the question :)

Comment: @Lynn I am writing a brief history on software development for my master thesis and with this sentence I am in the early 1950's :)

Comment: @StoneyB yes, i meant exactly this: first source code had to be tested **and** executed manually and **then** run on a real computer.

Comment: @marcwellman  In that case I still have to ask What's the difference between "test" and "execute"? Isn't the "test" a dry-run "execution"? If that's the case, then I think what you want is something more like *It was common practice to test a program's source code by manual execution before running it on a computer.* And ifn it wuz me, I'd put the substance of Lynn's comment in dashes between "execution" and before", to demonstrate what a pain in the ass it was and why the invention of assembler and higher-level languages was so important.

Comment: @marcwellman: Your timeframe certainly predates my personal knowledge (and probably even StoneyB's!), but my understanding is the first "language" (Fortran) wasn't directly supported on actual hardware [until 1957](http://www.enotes.com/computerscience/q-and-a/which-was-first-computer-language-202641). So in the *early* 50s all they had was *machine code* (which I suppose you could call *source code*, but I don't think that's how we generally understand the term today).